# Date Comparison and copy only new files

Tags: file, date, vbscript, comparison, backup

Good morning,
I'm a beginner in programming code, so i'm sorry if I do something wrong.
I've wrote a code in VBS for backup some files from a folder to another.
My problem it is to compare the files date in both folders and allow the copy only if the file is new or the date has been changed.
Here my code, someone can help me to find the problem please? 
I have tried but it is not working

```
    ' Copy a Folder


'Const OverWriteFiles = False
Dim strSourceFolder, strDestFolder
strSourceFolder = "E:\test1"
strDestFolder = "C:\test1"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFolder "strSourceFolder" , "strDestFolder" 

For each file in StrSourceFolder
     ReplaceIfNewer ("file, strDestFolder")
Next

Sub ReplaceIfNewer (SourceFile, DestFolder)

    Dim DateModifiedSourceFile, DateModifiedDestFile
    DateModifiedSourceFile = SourceFile.DateModified()
    DateModifiedDestFile = DestFolder & "\" & SourceFile.DateModified()

    If DateModifiedSourceFile < DateModifiedDestFile then
        Copy SourceFile to SourceFolder Else
        End If


' Verify that a Folder Exists


'Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists("strDestFolder") Then  
MsgBox  "Backup Copy Done." & vbCrLf & (Day(Now) & "\" & Month(Now) & "\" & Year(Now)) , Vbinformation
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("strDestFolder")
Else


MsgBox  "Folder does not exist." , vbCritical , "Folder does not exist." 



End if
```

Thanks and Be patient !

Comment: You may be interested in [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

.DateModified is not VBScript. Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c8xh895w(v=vs.84).aspx). There is [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595(v=vs.84).aspx), but as Dates are Doubles under the hood, comparisons with [<](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx) will work too. In code:

```
>> Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName)
>> dlm = f.DateLastModified
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(dlm), dlm, "(german locale)"
>> dlmn = DateAdd("s", 2, dlm)
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(dlmn), dlmn, "(german locale)"
>> WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", dlmn, dlm), DateDiff("s", dlm, dlmn), CStr(dlm < dlmn)
>> WScript.Echo CDbl(dlm)
>> WScript.Echo CDbl(dlmn)
>>
Date 22.11.2013 13:09:53 (german locale)
Date 22.11.2013 13:09:55 (german locale)
-2 2 Wahr
41600,5485300926
41600,5485532407
```